# How do i make the hover state for blog posts on the homepage the default?

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, blogs

I am using this theme for a website:

[click here to view the wordpress theme demo](http://andersnoren.se/themes/hitchcock/)

On the homepage, it displays blog posts WITHOUT the blog post title/date. It only displays this information when you hover over it.

How can I remove this state? I would like the blog post title and date to always be visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to edit the style.css file. If you look in Chrome's developer tools on the demo you linked to, and highlight one of the squares which has the hover effect, you can see that on line 649 of the style.css file there's a rule for `.post-overlay:hover` which changes the opacity to 1.

All you need to do is set `.post-overlay {opacity: 1; }` in style.css (note the lack of ":hover"), and remove the `:hover` rule. This will mean that the opacity is *always* 1 (100% opaque), not just when the cursor is hovering over the element.

Comment: I've just seen that there's more than one thing happening when the curser hovers over: the opacity changes and also the text moves down slightly. From a user experience point of view, it's nice to have something happen on hover - it lets users know that they can interact with an element. The text moving slightly might not be what you want, so play around with some other effects (https://miketricking.github.io/dist/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a css rule in style.css (line #654) that is controlling that fade in effect:

```
has-post-thumbnail .post-overlay{
background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
opacity: 0; }
```

The opacity changes to 1 when hovered, and the background gives the darkened effect.  Change these css rules and you'll get the effect you are looking for.

set like so:

```
has-post-thumbnail .post-overlay{
opacity:1; }
```

This will get rid of the darker background and make the text visible. You'll still have the corresponding text animations in the following rules to set as you like. (the rule that governs these is { .post .post-overlay, .has-post-thumbnail .archive-post-header } and is on on line 193)

Use firebug in firefox to edit these parameters live before you edit.